# Rule Based Design

Tags: c++, rules, business-rules

I will regularly read some discrete states, and applying some rules to differences in states I will report some errors. **Rules can be changed in time.**

What are best-practices to solve such a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Rules can be changed in time does it mean in real time ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but hearing ideas about also real time could be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also use the singleton pattern, apart from the Strategy one.
One possible implementation (though this is quite open, if you want a flexible set of rules you shoud use another class for the "Rule" entity. However, this way it is simpler to understand):

```
class Rules {
public:
    virtual bool rule_1(Data *) = 0;
    // ...
    virtual bool rule_n(Data *) = 0;

    static Rules * getRules()
        {
            // The only place in which to change the rule set
            if ( ruleSet == NULL ) ruleSet = new Rules_September2010();
            return ruleSet;
        }
protected:
    Rules();
    static Rules * ruleSet;
};

class Rules_August2010 : public Rules {
public:
    bool rule_1(Data *);
    bool rule_n(Data *);
};

class Rules_September2010 : public Rules {
public:
    bool rule_1(Data *);
    bool rule_n(Data *);
};
```

Of course this is an indication of the header(s). The implementation files are missing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

What first comes to my mind is the Gof' [Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) called [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

You encode your rules in the Concrete Strategy objects.
So you could have a particular Concrete Strategy object that is changing in time.
But best is to change of Concrete Strategy objects to reflect the new rule, IMHO.

The wikipedia link has an example in C++. But if you are new to design patterns and/or need further explanations about it, just ask.